# Xcode 15 - Building for ios but linking in dylib built for ios-simulator

Tags: python, ios, iphone, xcode, kivy

I developed a kivy app that works totally fine on the simulator, but when I want to build in a device, I get the following error:

"Building for ios but linking in dylib built for ios-simulator"
If it helps, here the full error:
Building for 'iOS', but linking in dylib (/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/MessageUI.framework/MessageUI.tbd) built for 'iOS-simulator'

I'm using Xcode 15, but I wasn't having this problem with earlier versions, even with the same python file! I still have myapp-ios from the older Xcode and it still builds fine on my iPhone, but with newapp-ios from the new Xcode, the building fails. So I really don't understand why this is happening now.

Additionally, I get another error:
"Linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)"

I'm new to app development and I really don't know what to do. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

So, I found this post [Xcode project (originally Python Kivy) not building to iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77187827/xcode-project-originally-python-kivy-not-building-to-iphone) and it fixed the issues I was having!

Then I had a (new) second issue but this post https://github.com/kivy/kivy-ios/issues/787 fixed it!

Now my newapp is built and working on my device!